# can an array be initialized with a value that is returned by a function

Tags: c++, arrays, function

```
    if(b[s][e]!=0)
    {
        return b[s][e];
    }
    else
    {
        int b[s][e]=palin(str,s+1,e-1)+2;
    }
```

I am initializing this array with a value that is returned by function palin and it is giving the following error:
**[Error] array must be initialized with a brace-enclosed initializer**

Comment: The remaining code, please.

Comment: No, you can't do it with built-in arrays. You can with `std::array` though.

Comment: I suspect you meant to do something more like this instead: `if (b[s][e] == 0) { b[s][e] = palin(str, s+1, e-1)+2; } return b[s][e];`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With

```
int b[s][e]=...;
```

you **define a new array** of `s` arrays of `e` integer elements.

If you want to assign a value to `b[s][e]` just do it:

```
b[s][e] = ...;
```

Answer (score 0):

You may not use:

```
    int b[s][e]=palin(str,s+1,e-1)+2;
```

That defines a new array.

Perhaps you meant to use

```
    b[s][e]=palin(str,s+1,e-1)+2;
```

Comment: Well, judging by the title of the question, "defines a new array" is exactly what the OP wanted to do.

Comment: thanks man. sometimes I feel where is my common sense :p

Comment: @RaghuvendraKaushik, don't feel too bad. Most of us have been through this kinds of moments along the way.